# If F is differentiable at c, then f is continuous at c

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I am having trouble coming up with a counterpoint to this claim.
I did some work on it, but I don't think it actually makes sense. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqsMX.jpg I'm doing part (c). Are there any minds more capable than mine that can check my work?

EDIT:

Question: Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, let $F(x)=\int_a^x f$, (a<=x<=b), and let $c$ be in $(a,b)$. For each of the following statements, give either a proof or a counterexample.

(c) If $F$ is differentiable at $c$, then $f$ is continuous at $c$

Comment: Be careful with (a). The formulation of FTC that I know need $f$ to be continuous in an interval, not just at a point

Comment: You should state the problem here, not at a link that may disappear in time.

Comment: In your computation $F(x)=\begin{cases}x-1/2,&\text{ for }x\in[1/2,1]\\0,&\text{ for }x\in[0,1/2]\end{cases}$, which is not differentiable at $x=1/2$. Notice that your computation $F(x)=x-1/2$ is only valid for $x\in[1/2,1]$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Continuity at a point suffices.

Comment: Take the function $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq 1/2+1/n$, for $n=2,3,4,...$ and $f(1/2+1/n)=1$. Then $F(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$, which is differentiable on all of $[0,1]$ and int particular at $x=1/2$, but $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1/2$.

Comment: @LB_O Thanks, that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 4):

Let $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $F(x) = x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ with $F(0) = 0$.

Let $G(x) := F(x) - F(-1)$. Since $F$ is everywhere differentiable with an integrable derivative, it follows that.

$$G(x) = \int_{-1}^{x} F'$$

We can note that $G$ is differentiable at $0$, but $F'$ is not continuous there.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the term

$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$
and calculate the Limit for $x$ tends to $x_0$

Comment: This answer does not address the question.

Comment: And can you tell me why?

Comment: Cuz the conditions in (c) are satisfied by some $f$'s and not by others, i.e. the general statement is false. A computation for a general $f$ wouldn't show this.

Comment: You're assuming that he's trying to show that if $f$ is differentiable then $f$ is continuous. The actual question is totally different.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Please delete your answer; you seem to have misread the problem.